# Explicit example of wall-crossing for sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

I would like to see an explicit example of a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ on a projective complex threefold $X$ which crosses the wall of stability. That is, I would like some $1$-parameter family $\omega_t$ of Kähler forms such that $\mathcal{E}$ is $\mu_t$-stable for $t>0$ and $\mu_t$-unstable for $t\leq 0$. Of course, I tried to come up with examples of this myself. However, it seems like all the convenient spaces prevent this phenomenon from happening: curves (which aren't threefolds, but just to see what was going on), hypersurfaces, complete intersections in $\mathbb{CP}^N$, etc., because in each case, $h^{1,1}(X)=1$. This implies that the Kähler cone is just a ray, so fixing a Kähler class $\omega$ as basis, any $1$-parameter family of Kähler classes may be written as $\omega_t=a(t)\omega$ for some function $a(t)>0$. For any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, it follows that
$$\text{deg}_t(\mathcal{F})=\int_Xc_1(\mathcal{F})\wedge\omega_t^{n-1}=a(t)^{n-1}\int_Xc_1(\mathcal{F})\wedge\omega^{n-1}=a(t)^{n-1}\text{deg}(\mathcal{F})$$
Consequently, for any subsheaf $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{E}$, we get $\mu_t(\mathcal{F})<\mu_t(\mathcal{E})\iff \mu(\mathcal{F})<\mu(\mathcal{E})$ for all $t$. Is this reasoning correct? If so, are there any relatively simple examples of coherent sheaves which do exhibit the wall-crossing phenomenon?